# Get count of terms with a post and another taxonomy term?

Tags: count, terms

How do I count the number of taxonomy terms which have both a) an associated post and b) where that post also has an associated term from another taxonomy?

Specifically, I have...

- Custom post type "`article`" (9,000+ posts)
- Custom taxonomy "`format`" (11 terms)
- Custom taxonomy "`company`" (1,624 terms)

An article is taggable with both a "`format`" and a "`company`".

**I want to get a count of the number of "companies" about which there is an "`article`" with the "`format`" term "`viewpoint`" or, more importantly, any of its 3 children.** How can I do this?

Ordinarily, I think the question would be "How do I count the number of '`articles`' tagged with any '`company`'"? Except that I would like specifically those qualifying articles to be of the "`format`" taxonomy's "`viewpoint`" term or one of its children.

Am I thinking of this backward? Is this about asking: "Find all '`articles`' tagged with both any '`company`' and '`format`' of '`viewpoint`', and then return a count of those '`articles`'"?

I think I should avoid a `WP_Query` as we are talking about a large number of items here, especially for "`article`". What is an efficient way?

I feel like `get_object_term` coupled with children may be useful here?

The following code does something different (counts the number of objects with "`viewpoint`" or a child alone. But maybe it's a start...

```
  // Get Viewpoints total count
  $term = get_term_by('slug', 'viewpoint', 'format');
  $id = $term->term_id;
  $count = 0;
  $taxonomy = 'format';
  $args = array('child_of' => $id);
  $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy,$args);
  foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
    if ($tax_term->parent == $id) {
          $count +=$tax_term->count;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Rather struggling with this, as everything seems to be database-intensive, leading to long load times.